# Transform XML files in folder when viewed in browser

Tags: xml, xslt, iis-7

I am working with XML files being used for machine to machine information exchange, and need to view certain parts of the files when troubleshooting.  I have created an XSLT to produce the desired output in HTML, but to use it I have to open the XSL and XML files in an editor application to perform the transform, save the file and view in a browser.  So a multi-step operation that requires a bit of attention to detail.  This is a Windows Server 2012 environment with the folder containing the XML files designated as a virtual directory on that server.

What I would like is for the server-side to apply the XSL transform to all the XML files in the folder when served to a browser client.

I've looked at a lot of different ways to automate the transform, but without being able to edit the XML file contents it seems like it would require some unique application development and introduce additional dependencies.  It seems like the masterPageFile in IIS might be a mechanism to do this, but I am wondering if there are some other ways to accomplish this.

Comment: There are lots of content management systems that manage on-demand XML-to-HTML transformation server side (eg Adobe DreamWeaver, Altova Flowforce) though I'm not sure what the current preferred choice would be. But rigging up a do-it-yourself transformation servet in Java isn't difficult.

Comment: Server-side XSLT processing can be accomplished using a number of different technologies, including ASP.NET, PHP, Java, and Perl, depending on the technology you use and the resources available.